# Is there any way to reference other elements with `map` or `select`?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array of numbers:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 90, 4, 5, 6 ..., 10]
```

I'd like to remove any item (e.g. `90`) that is "too much different" from its neighbours.

Is there a `map`/`select_with_index` by which I could reference previous/next items?

```
a.select { |i| i.too_much_different? i.prev, i.next }
```

Comment: You need to specify what you mean by "too much different". Give us a specific, unambigous rule. Also, if `90` is to be removed from your array, is `4` then compared with `3` and `5` or with `90` and `5`?

Comment: `Enumerable#each_cons(2)` may be used for such task, but to make it more clear, how should be considered next sibling element when previous was discarded ?

Comment: The short answer is: not in the way you're suggesting since the single element is passed in as a block argument and has no knowledge of being part of an array at that point with previous or next values. But as @joanbm suggest, `Enumerable#each_cons` could work for you. I'd probably use `Enumerable#each_cons(3)` based upon what I *think* you are saying you want as a criteria. But you do need to clarify. What about the list `[1,2,3,20,21,22,8,9,25,26]`? Which elements are really the *deviant* ones?

Comment: too_much_different? is to be defined... (ex.: may be +- 3, or use SD).
My doubt is whether I can reference other elements from inside the block.

Comment: If what you're really trying to do is throw out statistical outliers, there are proper functional ways to do that.

Comment: @lurker then the question is misleading. If the whole set is known in advance, this would be a different story.

Comment: @joanbm I think the question is unclear, not really misleading. However, unclear and misleading can lead to the same misunderstandings. Since we're dealing with Ruby arrays, of course the entire array is known. What's not known is the purpose behind what the OP is trying to do which has a bearing on what implementation would be most appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something like this I would suggest a regular loop rather than trying to coerce it into matching a ruby enumerable method. However, you could do it like this if you want:

```
a.reject.with_index do |el, i|
  # conditions involving el
  # next el is a[i+1]
  # previous el is a[i-1]
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the idea to find an absolute filter criteria:

```
data = [1, 2, 3, 90, 4, 5, 6, 10]

def reject_value(data)
  max = data.max
  min = data.min
  sum = 0
  data.each {|item| sum += item}
  avg = sum / data.length
  puts "MAX " + max.to_s + "| MIN " + min.to_s + "| AVG " + avg.to_s
  avg
end

filter = reject_value(data)

refined_values = data.reject {|item| item >= filter}

puts refined_values.join(", ")
```